# Why use Host Port: 3333 and Guest Port: 22 in Linux?

Tags: linux

In a tutorial, after installing Linux in VirtualBox, it just let me set Host Port to 3333 and Guest Port to 22 without any explanation. Is there any reason for us to do that?

[image]

Comment: Why downvote my post without any reason?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In VirtualBox terminology, the host is the system where you have VirtualBox installed - where you define and configure your VMs. The guest is the VM itself.

The type of network you have configured for this VM is NAT (Network Address Translation). In this configuration, the host and the guest share the underlying network interface. This is the simplest configuration, but is also means that you cannot access the VM using a unique IP address.

That's where port forwarding comes in. When you enable port forwarding, you can take a port on the guest system and set it up to be accessible from a port on the host system. In the config you've shown here, port 22 on the guest (a well-defined port used for SSH) is forwarded to port 3333 (a random port) on the host.

Once this configuration is in place, you can run `ssh ssh://username@localhost:3333` or `ssh -p 3333 username@localhost` from the host to establish a connection to the guest VM via SSH. Perhaps the tutorial includes this same command at a later stage.

Further reading: [VirtualBox documentation on NAT configuration and Port Forwarding](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_nat)